# Tab is undefined while rendering chart with JQPlot through JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, tabs, jqplot

Using `jqplot` for rendering bar-chart on 4 different tabs on the same page. The following piece of code is supposed to bind the tabs to the related chart.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GvW4U/1/)

```
...
var tab;
... 
$(document).ready(function(){
...
...
     305   $('#tabs').bind('tabsactivate', function(event, ui){      
     306        tab=ui.newTab.index();
     307        plotObj[0][tab].replot();
     308        plotObj[1][tab].replot();
      });
...
...
});
```

The error I get is :

**TypeError: plotObj[1](http://jsfiddle.net/GvW4U/1/)[tab] is null**

**plotObj[1](http://jsfiddle.net/GvW4U/1/)[tab].value.replot();**

**Problem:** Can't seem to point out the problem of tab being undefined.

Hovering upon the **tab** variable on line 306 shows *undefined*, where tab is already defined at the beginning.

Just after that event there is a function call which makes an `AJAX` call to another file

```
PlotTimeSeries();
```

[Code details](http://jsfiddle.net/GvW4U/1/)

Comment: Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/GvW4U/1/